# Image processing C#

Tags: c#, image, pixel-shader

I have a function to check if an image is just one color.

```
bool r = true;
Color checkColor = image.GetPixel(0, 0);

for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
  {
   for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
     {
      if (image.GetPixel(x, y) != checkColor) { r = false; }
     }
   }
// image color
clrOut = checkColor;
return r;
```

But this algorithm is slow for big images. 
Does anyone knows a way to do this using Pixel Shaders and GPU?

Answer (score 6):

You don't need pixel shaders and a GPU to speed this up. Use [LockBits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits).  Bob Powell has a good [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20141229164101/http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx) on doing exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Also looking at your code, try reversing the for loops it gives better  memory access

for( y...
 ...
  for ( x...

The next step is to unroll some of the pixels access.  Try  fetching 4 or 8 pixels  in the inter loop

for( y...
 ...
  for ( x  = 0; x < image.Width  ;  x +=4 )

```
  pixel0 = image.getpixel(x,Y)
  pixel1 = image.getpixel(x +1,Y)
  pixel2 = image.getpixel(x +2,Y)
  pixel3 = image.getpixel(x +3,Y)

  if ( pixel0 ....
```

As stated earlier using Bitmap Unlock allows you access pixels via  pointers, which is the fastest you can get on a CPU.  You  can  apply loop ordering and pixel unrolling to that technique too.
If this isn't fast enough then  there is choice between; C# multi-threading or  GPU  with OpenCL and its C# binding.

Answer (score 1):

This code is slow, because you use `GetPixel`. You can make it *much* faster by using direct pointer access. Only if that's not enough, I'd look into pixel shaders.

I've written some helper libraries: https://github.com/CodesInChaos/ChaosUtil/tree/master/Chaos.Image

In particular the `Pixels` and the `RawColor` types should be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only looking for an image with large areas of variation versus one with the same color, you could shrink it down to a 1x1 pixel using Bilinear filtering and read pixel 0,0. 
If the the pixel is VERY different from what you expect (RGB distance versus a tolerance), you can be sure that there was some variation in the original image.

Of course, this depends on what you really want to do with this info so YMMV.